# Translating C++ Classes to Delphi

Tags: c++, delphi, translation, abstract-class

I am translating some C++ code to Delphi and there are some abstract classes that need to be translated. These classes are used as parameter/return types, etc, and my question is if a C++ class hierarchy such as this:

```
class Thing {
    virtual void blah() = 0;
};

class Thing2 : public Thing {
    virtual bool asdf(Thing*) = 0;
};
```

can be rewritten in Delphi as:

```
Thing = class
    procedure blah; virtual;
end;

Thing2 = class(Thing)
    function asdf(Thing) : Boolean; virtual;
end;
```

And the Delphi code can call C++ functions that take C++ Thing*s and stuff, and C++ code can call Delphi functions that take Delphi Things, etc. So basically, if the above translation is made, will a C++ Thing2* equal a Delphi Thing2 where Delphi can call it's methods, etc?

Comment: You might want to read Rudy Velthuis' article "Using C++ objects in Delphi" (http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite.  In C++, marking a method as `= 0` means it's an abstract method.  In Delphi, to get the same effect, you have to mark it as `virtual; abstract;`, not just as `virtual;`.

Also, in Delphi, if you place a class member declaration immediately under the class name, it'll be declared by default as `published`, which means it's public plus RTTI is generated for it.  That's probably not your intention, so put a visibility scope declaration (`private, protected` or `public`) first:

```
Thing = class
public
    procedure blah; virtual; abstract;
end;

Thing2 = class(Thing)
public
    function asdf(Thing) : Boolean; virtual; abstract;
end;
```

Comment: So then adding abstract after virtual will make a Thing2* in C++ equivalent to a Thing2 in Delphi?

Comment: Sorry, one more thing, should I mark those functions stdcall or cdecl? And for varargs functions (like virtual void blah(...)) those are cdecl right?

Comment: @John: Wait, are you trying to make a Delphi class that matches a C++ class so you can pass them back and forth between an app and a DLL and pretend they're equivalent?  *Don't do that!* There are all sorts of other details that are not likely to line up properly.  If you want to do that sort of communication between languages with different object models and different memory management, look into COM.  That's what it was designed for, and it works much better than trying to overlay classes on each other.